# Rails validator: Only add if occurred_at is after latest entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have an `Event` model that stores tracking events from carriers (Shipped, Out for delivery, Delivered, etc etc).

We ping the carrier API's on a regular basis to get new status updates, but I only want to add new tracking "events" if their `occurred_at` date/time is after the latest entry.

So if the last event we have occurred at "2011-08-19 06:44:00" then only events that have a later date/time should be added.

I'm trying to do something like this, but in a validator:

```
last_event = Event.find_by_number_id(id, :order => 'occurred_at DESC')
if !last_event || (new_event.occurred_at > last_event.occurred_at)
  new_event.save
end
```

I'm running Rails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a real validator, but you could use something like:

```
validate do
  last_event = Event.find_by_number_id(id, :order => 'occurred_at DESC')
  errors.add(:occured_at, :invalid) if !last_event || (new_event.occurred_at > last_event.occurred_at)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom validation method or use default `validate` method. Just put your code into validation method and return `errors.add(:some_error, "some message")` when it fails criteria. Take a look at this guide: [Rails validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers)